# cap production deploy Don't know how to build task 'start' (see --tasks)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my error

cap production deploy
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'start' (see --tasks)

with --trace https://gist.github.com/hmexp/a899739fc39eeb56b20f639965a54b13

Capfile

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rails/console'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/puma'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

Deploy.rb 
https://gist.github.com/hmexp/58ac59bd9af48922835c7fcc73fe7ece

So how can i fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue some weeks ago.

As far as I remember, I solved this by putting my `before` and `after` statements outside of namespaces and therefore precising the namespaces in invokations like the following:

```
before "deploy:starting", "deploy:setup_maintenance_for_deploy"
before "deploy:starting", "maintenance:enable"
# after 'deploy:migrate', 'deploy:seed'
after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
after "deploy:finished", "maintenance:disable"
```

Your trace seems also to confirm my intuition that the problem is caused by a namespacing issue.
These are the Capfile and deploy.rb I'm using:

[Capfile](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d8e8a803bdbef9e024fc5384c395c8c5)
[deploy.rb](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/32900b0a99fe096d8103b3082e74d5f8)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you need to add `install_plugin Capistrano::Puma` into your Capfile after `require 'capistrano/puma'` as indicated from other SO questions.

For my case, don't put `before` and `after` hooks inside any custom capistrano .rake file. These hooks are meant to be inside deploy.rb.